# Environment variables undefined using dotenv

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, undefined, dotenv

I have a file which connects to `Contentful` using my specific `space` and `accessToken`. Recently, I decided to hide the `keys` into an `.env` file using the `dotenv` package. This is what my file looks like :

```
import {createClient} from 'contentful';
require('dotenv').config();
//console.log('space = ', process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE);

const client = createClient({
  space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE,
  accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_TOKEN
});

export default client;
```

For some reason, the `env` variables are coming out as undefined. Currently, my `.env` file is under the root dir. This is the file structure of my project :

```
project
 client
  src
   service
    client.js <-- The file I pasted above
 node_modules
 .env
 package-lock.json
 package.json
```

Things I've tried :

1. Uninstalled `dotenv` and reinstalled it
2. Deleted `node_modules` folder and reinstalled all dependencies
3. Moved `.env` file under `service` folder where the `client` file exists
4. Used the `REACT_APP_*` prefix for my env variables in `.env` file
5. Specified the path in the `config` call

All of these solutions came from other `stackoverflow` questions. I've been stuck on this for a few days circling through the solutions listed and looking for others but still haven't figured out why I'm not able to access my `env` variables!

Comment: You aren't checking the return value of calling the `.config` method, according to the docs it will be an object with an error if it fails. You should add a minimal reproducable example including the contents of your .env file. Also as a piece of advice, begging people to not close your question is usually not going to help it get a better reception (if anything the opposite)...

Comment: Cool, will check that out and update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: '../../.env' });
```

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting a path to your .env file in the config.

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config({ path: '../../../.env' });
```

edit: config path

Answer (score 1):

So I tried structuring a sample project the same way you've structured it, and it didn't work. I moved the .env file under /service folder, it worked.
My guess is, requiring the dot env file should be on the main file that wraps your project (main file in the root), along with .env file.

Answer (score 1):

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../../.env')
});
```

This will resolver your issue

Answer (score 0):

make sure you set your env variables as "username=exampleusername", if you set "username:exampleusername" it will say undefined, semicolon maybe the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case:

```js
// app.js
const outsideSecret = process.env.API_SECRET; // <- Did NOT work

export class App {
  classSecret = process.env.API_SECRET; // <- Worked
  getSecret = () => {
    console.log(outsideSecret); // <- undefined
    console.log(this.classSecret); // <- Value in .env file
  }
}
```

```js
// index.js
import { config } from "dotenv";

import { App } from "./app.js";

config();
const app = new App();
app.getSecret();
```